# Upper bound for $\min_{x \geq 0} e^{t x} \cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-x u} f(u) du$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am dealing with the following function:

$$m(t) = \min_{x \geq 0}  e^{t x} \cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-x u} f(u) du,$$

where $t \geq 0$ and $f(u)$ is a pdf of a random variable $X$ distributed over $[0, \infty)$. It is clear that $m(0) = 0$, and $m(t)$ is increasing in $t$.

My question is: Is the function $m(t)$ continuous at $t = 0$? I conjecture that this can be bounded by some linear function, i.e., $m(t) \leq c \cdot t$ for constant $c > 0$, but I am unsure how to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is continuous, but there is no guaranteed rate of decay at $0$. To prove continuity, just take $\varepsilon>0$, choose $x>0$ so that the integral is $<\varepsilon$ and then choose $\delta=1/x$.